# IPython MPI with a Machinefile

Tags: ipython, mpi, distributed-computing

I want to use IPython's MPI abilities with distributed computing. Namely I would like MPI to be run with a machine file of sorts so I can add multiple machines.

EDIT:

I forgot to include my configuration.

Configuration

```
~/.ipython/profile_default/ipcluster_config.py
# The command line arguments to pass to mpiexec.                                
c.MPILauncher.mpi_args = ["-machinefile ~/.ipython/profile_default/machinefile"]


# The mpiexec command to use in starting the process.                           
c.MPILauncher.mpi_cmd = ['mpiexec']
```

Bash Execution

```
$ dacluster start -n20
2015-06-10 16:16:46.661 [IPClusterStart] Starting ipcluster with [daemon=False]
2015-06-10 16:16:46.661 [IPClusterStart] Creating pid file: /home/aidan/.ipython/profile_default/pid/ipcluster.pid
2015-06-10 16:16:46.662 [IPClusterStart] Starting Controller with MPI
2015-06-10 16:16:46.700 [IPClusterStart] ERROR | IPython cluster: stopping
2015-06-10 16:16:47.667 [IPClusterStart] Starting 20 Engines with MPIEngineSetLauncher
2015-06-10 16:16:49.701 [IPClusterStart] Removing pid file: /home/aidan/.ipython/profile_default/pid/ipcluster.pid
```

Machinefile

```
~/.ipython/profile_default/machinefile

localhost slots=8
aidan-slave slots=16
```

I might mention that it works when I run

```
mpiexec -machinefile machinefile mpi_hello
```

And the output of that execution includes hostnames, so I am sure it is actually distributing. Plus I watch on top.

Thank you,

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry, Why am I getting the errors listed in the Bash Execution? And how do I fix them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I asked too soon. the problem was in the below line

```
c.MPILauncher.mpi_args = ["-machinefile ~/.ipython/profile_default/machinefile"]
```

It should have been split on the spaces with absolute path

```
c.MPILauncher.mpi_args = ["-machinefile", "/home/aidan/.ipython/profile_default/machinefile"]
```

I hope this can help someone. Note that this solves only the problem in the BASH output. The connection is made with MPI to a remote server (namely aidan-slave). If start the dacluster, then I see in top a bunch of python sessions start, symptomatic of a IPython session running remotely.

Unfortunately, DistArray examples, at least pi_montecarlo, hang indefinitely. I worked back to the source of the issue and found that the line that is hanging in line 736 in the context.py file of the globalapi module in distarray.

```
def _execute(self, lines, targets):
    return self.view.execute(lines, targets=targets, block=True)
```

I think this is a symptom of a broken or bad MPI connection because the line seems to want to execute a command on all the slaves processes. I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: No. I just gave up and wrote the MPI code myself. Depending on what you want to do, I would recommend (after months of hacking around with MPI) to just write the code yourself and use https://www.cs.uoregon.edu/research/tau/home.php to profile your code for further optimization. The literature on parallelization with MPI usually uses OpenMP to parallelize locally and then uses MPI to communicate between different nodes in a cluster.